# Pyspark: Create new column of the set of values in a groupby

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["2020-05-10", "2020-05-10", "2020-05-10", "2020-05-11", "2020-05-11", "2020-05-12", ], "Mode": ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B']})

df = spark.createDataFrame(df)

+----------+----+
|      Date|Mode|
+----------+----+
|2020-05-10|   A|
|2020-05-10|   B|
|2020-05-10|   A|
|2020-05-11|   C|
|2020-05-11|   C|
|2020-05-12|   B|
+----------+----+
```

And I would like to groupby the `Date` and create a new column of the set of values in the `Mode` column like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["2020-05-10", "2020-05-10", "2020-05-10", "2020-05-11", "2020-05-11", "2020-05-12", ], "Mode": ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B'], "set(Mode)": [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B'], ['C'], ['C'], ['B']]})

df = spark.createDataFrame(df)

+----------+----+---------+
|      Date|Mode|set(Mode)|
+----------+----+---------+
|2020-05-10|   A|   [A, B]|
|2020-05-10|   B|   [A, B]|
|2020-05-10|   A|   [A, B]|
|2020-05-11|   C|      [C]|
|2020-05-11|   C|      [C]|
|2020-05-12|   B|      [B]|
+----------+----+---------+
```

​

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `collect_set` over a window:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn("Set",F.collect_set('Mode')
                     .over(Window.partitionBy("Date"))).orderBy("Date").show()
```

---

```
+----------+----+------+
|      Date|Mode|   Set|
+----------+----+------+
|2020-05-10|   A|[B, A]|
|2020-05-10|   A|[B, A]|
|2020-05-10|   B|[B, A]|
|2020-05-11|   C|   [C]|
|2020-05-11|   C|   [C]|
|2020-05-12|   B|   [B]|
+----------+----+------+
```

If exact order matters:

```
(df.withColumn("idx",F.monotonically_increasing_id())
   .withColumn("Set",F.collect_set('Mode').over(Window.partitionBy("Date")))
   .orderBy("idx").drop("idx")).show()

+----------+----+------+
|      Date|Mode|   Set|
+----------+----+------+
|2020-05-10|   A|[B, A]|
|2020-05-10|   B|[B, A]|
|2020-05-10|   A|[B, A]|
|2020-05-11|   C|   [C]|
|2020-05-11|   C|   [C]|
|2020-05-12|   B|   [B]|
+----------+----+------+
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try below code

```
# Import Libraries
import pandas as pd

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["2020-05-10", "2020-05-10", "2020-05-10", "2020-05-11", "2020-05-11", "2020-05-12", ], "Mode": ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B']})
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)

# Group By on Date anc collect the values as set using collect_set function.
df1 = df.groupBy("Date").agg(collect_set("Mode"))

# Join the DataFrames to get desired result.
df2 = df.join(df1, "Date")

# Display DataFrame
df2.show()
```

## Output

```
+----------+----+-----------------+
|      Date|Mode|collect_set(Mode)|
+----------+----+-----------------+
|2020-05-11|   C|              [C]|
|2020-05-11|   C|              [C]|
|2020-05-10|   A|           [B, A]|
|2020-05-10|   B|           [B, A]|
|2020-05-10|   A|           [B, A]|
|2020-05-12|   B|              [B]|
+----------+----+-----------------+
```

I hope this helps.